# How to list current running JVMs using the Attach API

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, aop, cglib

**ENV**
tomcat7 jdk1.6

**TRIED** using JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import ="com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine" %>
<%@ page import ="com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor" %>
```

with

```
<%  
   out.print("Number of runtime jvms : "+VirtualMachine.list().size());
   for (int i=0; i<VirtualMachine.list().size(); i++) {
       VirtualMachineDescriptor vi = VirtualMachine.list().get(i);
       out.println("**PID :"+vi.id()+" **DISPLAYNAME:"+vi.displayName());
   }
%>
```

**Result**

```
Number of runtime jvms : 0
```

I expected it to not be `0`. There are several running JVMs. Can anyone give me some advices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is described in the javadoc of [`VirtualMachine#list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#list%28%29):

> The list is an **aggregation of the virtual machine descriptor lists
>   obtained by invoking the `listVirtualMachines` method of all installed
>   attach providers**. If there are no Java virtual machines known to any
>   provider then an empty list is returned.

*Bold formatting was added by me.*

The `VirtualMachine#list()` method only returns the running JVM instances that are known to the current JVM processes. Each such process is identified by an implementation of [`AttachProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/spi/AttachProvider.html). I can only guess but I assume that calling [`AttachProvider#providers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/spi/AttachProvider.html#providers%28%29) will yield an empty list. If this is the case, make sure that you add implementations of `AttachProvider` accessible on the class path. Note that these providers must also be visible to the `ClassLoader` of `VirtualMachine`.

An example of an `AttachProvider` is for example the [`HotSpotAttachProvider`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/tools/attach/HotSpotAttachProvider.java.html) which is a provider listing running instances of any HotSpot Virtual Machine.